# OSM data: "Referenced nodes" vs regular nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I am using `osm2po` software to extract nodes and edges from `europe-latest.osm.pbf`. When run from terminal, the logs are as follows:

[image]

So, there are over 2 billion nodes, but only (or "only") around 197 million "referenced" nodes. Now my question is, what **is** a referenced node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess for osm2po "referenced nodes" are nodes which are part of a way.

In [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) each way has a list of referenced nodes, defined via `<nd ref=""/>` attributes:

```
<node id="298884269" lat="54.0901746" lon="12.2482632" user="SvenHRO" uid="46882" visible="true" version="1" changeset="676636" timestamp="2008-09-21T21:37:45Z"/>
...
<way id="26659127" user="Masch" uid="55988" visible="true" version="5" changeset="4142606" timestamp="2010-03-16T11:47:08Z">
 <nd ref="292403538"/>
 <nd ref="298884289"/>
 ...
 <nd ref="261728686"/>
 <tag k="highway" v="unclassified"/>
 <tag k="name" v="Pastower Straße"/>
</way>
```